# Decision making in Pipeline stalls

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture, risc

A load word instruction is immediately followed by a branch instruction(of mips 32).

```
lw r2, (0)r1;-- I swap registers here as opposed to my previous question
Beq r2, r3, target;
```

To produce a execution diagram, `IF ID EX MEM WB`. Now where should the stall be for `BEQ`

```
IF ID EX MEM WB
   IF *  *   ID EX

or 

IF ID EX MEM WB
   *  *  IF  ID  EX
```

I just want to understand if both ways are possible. Also, what hardware manipulation is involved for such stalls?

Comment: Is this supposed to represent a MIPS 2201 instruction set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple pipeline you show, `lw` is still being decoded while the next insn is being fetched.  The pipeline can't tell that they conflict until they're both decoded.

Think through exactly what your 2nd stall is doing:  The CPU delays fetching the next instruction before the current one is even decoded.  It doesn't know what either instruction is at this point.

```
IF ID EX MEM WB     lw
   *  IF ID  EX     beq  // lw isn't even decoded yet, and neither is this one, so no way to tell if they conflict.
```

---

re: your update: `IF` isn't an instruction, it's a pipeline stage.

---

BTW, the question was *much* clearer before you removed the pipeline diagrams.  You should put them back in, with code formatting (select the text and click the {} icon, or hit ctrl-k.)

Comment: Thanks, I realized I made quite a few errors in my question. Shouldn't the pipeline tell they conflict after the Instruction Fetch?

Comment: @ZacUwyoH: It can't tell anything until *both* instructions are decoded.  What if the second instruction was `add $r10, $r11, $r12`?  It doesn't know that until after the 2nd instruction is decoded.  So both the diagrams in the question are wrong, in your current edit.

Comment: would two stalls after ID work or what should be the solution?

Comment: @ZacUwyoH: It's the execute stage of `beq` that has to wait, and it has to wait for the result of the load to be known.  Without bypass forwarding, it also has to wait for the `WB` stage of the load, where the result is committed to the register file.  In that case, two stalls after after ID but before EX sounds right.

Comment: @ZacUwyoH: you can mark this as the accepted answer, with the checkbox under the vote arrows, if this answered your question.